# NaN returned when attempting to parse to float

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following jQuery code:

```
var total = parseFloat($(".hidden-total").text());
```

For some reason or other, total is being returned as NaN.

Could anyone suggest why?

Comment: What does $(".hidden-total").text() return?

Comment: Do you have more than one element with class .hidden-total on your page? If not, what is the textual content of that single element?

Comment: It returns a number as a string, for example '6.50'

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Comment: can you post the full code? it could be something else that is causing the trouble

Comment: `6.50` parses correctly so please post what `.text` is *exactly* returning.

Comment: if it actually returns '6.50' with the quotes then it won't work because it won't parse the ' but if it is just 6.50 it will work so if your .text() only returns 6.50 then there should be no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is inside of hidden-total? and how many of those are there?
.text() returns the concatenated string of all of the hidden-total class and other element inside of it. so if you have more than 1 it probably won't work

Answer (score 0):

NaN is a valid float, it is an abbreviation of NotANumber and is the result of `0/0`.